# Calculating $\min(x_1,x_2)$ and $\max(x_1,x_2)$ using a two-layer neural network

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, functional-equations, machine-learning, neural-networks

Suppose that $\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^2$ is a vector and we want to find the minimum and the maximum of its components, using a two-layer neural network: $$\vec{y} = f_2(W_2f_1(W_1\vec{x}+b_1)+b_2), \ \  W_1,W_2 \in \mathbb{R^{2x2}},b_1,b_2\in \mathbb{R^2} \tag{1}\\ y_1 = \min(\vec{x}) = \min(x_1 , x_2) \\ y_2 = \max(\vec{x}) = \max(x_1 , x_2)$$ It's well-known that $$\max(x_1 , x_2) = \frac12(x_1+x_2)+\frac12|x_1-x_2| \\ \min(x_1 , x_2) = \frac12(x_1+x_2)-\frac12|x_1-x_2|,$$ but these formulas can't be constructed using $(1)$ due to its architecture. The problem is that $f_1(.)$ and $f_2(.)$ operate element-wisely and the same function should be applied to the components. Also this problem prevents us to use $$\max(x_1,x_2) = \max(x_1-x_2,0) + x_2 = \text{ReLU}(x_1-x_2) + x_2 \\ \min(x_1,x_2) = -\max(x_1-x_2,0) + x_1 = -\text{ReLU}(x_1-x_2) + x_1$$ I've tried other activation functions, such as sign function and step function, but it didn't work. So the question is: what's the appropriate values for $W_1,W_2,b_1,b_2$ and functions $f_1(.),f_2(.)$ such that $y_1=\min(x_1,x_2)$ and $y_2=\max(x_1,x_2)$?

**Edit:** The instructor corrected the question: the using of different activation functions, in a single layer of neural network is allowed. Therefore, with this correction the question can be answered easily, with the help of mentioned formulas for $\text{max}$ and $\text{min}$, but I think it's interesting to show that $(1)$ can't be used to construct $\text{max}$ and $\text{min}$, so I keep the question open.

Comment: Can you write explicitly what are your constaints on $f_1$ and $f_2$?

Comment: @JürgenSukumaran They can be any real-valued functions. The only constraint is that they operate element-wisely. For example if we take $f_1(\vec{x})=\tanh(\vec{x})$ then $f_1(\vec{x}) = (\tanh(x_1),\tanh(x_2))$.

Comment: Are you allowed to have more than two nodes per layer?

Comment: @Kroki No, it's not allowed. The number of the layers and the nodes is fixed.

Comment: Are you sure it's possible?

Comment: @JürgenSukumaran Not really. I posted the question as it was given to me (it's a homework problem). I've tried many different combinations but all of them failed, mainly due to the element-wise operation of the functions.

Comment: @Joako Thanks but I don't see how that helps me. Would you explain more, please? Also note that I'm looking for a solution which gives us the exact value of the minimum and maximum, not an approximation.

Comment: Why don’t you look at it as a classification problem?

Comment: @TedBlack Yes it can be considered as a classification problem but how does that help?

Comment: If you use the Heaviside function $H(x)=1$ if $x>0$ and zero otherwise as the activation function then $H(x_1-x_2)=1$ if $\max (x_1,x_2)=x_1$ and zero otherwise. The reverse is true for $H(x_2-x_1)$.

Comment: @TedBlack But we want to have $$y_1 = \min(\vec{x}) = \min(x_1 , x_2) \\ y_2 = \max(\vec{x}) = \max(x_1 , x_2)$$ It's not enough to know that $x_1 \gt x_2$ or $x_1 \lt x_2$ holds.

Comment: @S.H.W What are the exact restrictions on $f_1$ and $f_2$?  You say $\max(x_1-x_2,0)$ isn't allowed - what about $\min(x_1-x_2,0)$?  If not, what is the exact condition that is ruling out those two functions, and what other functions is it ruling out?

Comment: @user6247850 Any real-valued function is allowed, I didn't say $\max(x_1-x_2,0)$ isn't allowed. The only restriction is that functions operate element-wisely. For example if we take $f_1(\vec{x}) = \text{ReLU}(\vec{x})$ then $f_1(\vec{x}) = (\text{ReLU}(x_1) , \text{ReLU}(x_2))$.

Comment: @user6247850 Note that $\max(x_1-x_2,0)$ can be constructed because $x_1 - x_2$ is a linear combination of $x_1$ and $x_2$. So we can choose the elements of $W_1$ such that the first element of $W_1\vec{x}$ is $x_1-x_2$. Then applying $\text{ReLU}(.)$ to this element yields $\text{ReLU}(x_1-x_2) = \max(x_1-x_2,0)$.

Comment: @S.H.W Ah, I see, I thought "this problem prevents us to use..." meant there was an external constraint.  Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: @user6247850 You are welcome! Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: It cannot be a classification problem if you must return values (it is a regression). I can see a solution if we assume $x_1,x_2 \geq 0$.

Comment: @TedBlack According to the question $x_1$ and $x_2$ belong to the real numbers but I think it's good if you post it as a partial answer. Maybe it's possible to prove that in general it's impossible to have $y_1 = \min(\vec{x}) = \min(x_1 , x_2), y_2 = \max(\vec{x}) = \max(x_1 , x_2)$.

Comment: Using your notes if $x_1,x_2>0$ then assume activation for first layer is $|-|$. Generate two nodes $|x_1+x_2|=x_1+x_2$ and $|x_1-x_2|$. In the second layer do not use an activation function; instead use weights $\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}$ to generate $\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}+\frac{|x_1-x_2|}{2}$ and weights $\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}$ to generate $\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}-\frac{|x_1-x_2|}{2}$. These are $\max(x_1,x_2)$, $\min(x_1,x_2)$ respectively.

Comment: @TedBlack Thanks. In fact your comment shows that the condition $x_1,x_2 \gt 0$ implicitly leads to two different activation functions: $f_1((x_1,x_2)) = (x_1 , |x_2|)$.

Comment: Actually  it works as long as $x_1+x_2>0$ since in this case $|x_1+x_2|=x_1+x_2$.

Comment: In the case $x_1+x_2<0$ you can use that $|x_1+x_2|=-(x_1+x_2)$ and adjust the weights of the second layer accordingly.

Comment: There is a paper (“Canonical piecewise-linear representation” by Chua and Deng) which is relevant Have no access if anyone could get it it would be great

Comment: @TedBlack I can email you if you want.

Comment: empeirikos2718@gmail.com Many thanks

Comment: @TedBlack I sent the email, I hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately the paper only confirms that $\max$ and $\min$ can be written in terms of the absolute function in the way you have already described (there are some results for cases where one of the lines separating different cases is of the form $x_i=c$ but this is not useful here). I think your instructor is trying to show you that this is no possible (@Jurgen Sukumaran makes a good point about this). As a classification problem it works since using $\mathrm{sgn}(x_1-x_2)$ and $\mathrm{sgn}(x_2-x_1)$ we can get a vector which shows which of the two values is the max.

Comment: @TedBlack Thanks for the time you spent on this. Yes it seems that's impossible. I leave the question open, maybe someone can prove the impossibility result.

Comment: Can you ask the person who gave you the homework problem for a solution for us all?

Comment: @JürgenSukumaran I asked and he responded that the using of different activation functions in a single layer of neural network is allowed :). So the answer is trivial in this case, we can simply use the mentioned formulas for $\text{max}$ and $\text{min}$.

Comment: thank you for this closure.